# Longer than a word — smaller than a sentence

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, sentence, syntactic-analysis

What would you call a linguistic construct that is just big enough to convey a meaning within a context, longer than a word but not having the length and proper form of a complete sentence? Like, for example, "good job" or "nice shirt" — neither of those is a full sentence but both get the point across. A *sentencette*, or is there a formal term for it?

Comment: _Phrase_, or _clause_.

Comment: A comment or interjection?

Comment: @J.R.: A **phrase**, yes. But not a clause. A clause can be a phrase or a sentence.

Comment: @Cerberus: If a clause can be a phrase, then why couldn't you call it a clause?

Comment: i prefer CLAUSE

Comment: @foampile A clause has a more formal definition: it requires a predicate.

Comment: @J.R.: What is "it"? Foampile's examples weren't really clauses, were they?

Comment: A clause has a verb and an argument. A phrase does not have both.

Comment: @JohnLawler: *I left her, because she cheated on me all the time.* Now if I want to mention *she cheated on me* and say something about vowel sounds in that [thingamabob], what would you call it? I would call it a phrase. It may or may not be fitting to call it a clause (since it's not the entire clause as in the quotation), but I find it far more convenient to call that a phrase, because the relevant bit of information that I want to convey about it is just that it is a sequence of words.

Comment: @Cerberus: Well, _clause_ may be wrong, but I still think it's better than _sentencette_. ;^) Also, I presumed there was a much longer list of potential "sentencettes," besides the two mentioned in question (e.g., "look sharp" or "be cool" or "way to go" or "vote early, vote often"), so maybe some could be phrases, and some could be clauses.

Comment: @J.R.: Don't make me defend *sentencette*! Please! I can't do it! A word that I do enjoy is theorette, a mocking term for some silly theory.

Comment: If it's phonologically defined (i.e, you wanna talk about vowel sounds), it might should have a phonological name, like _stress group_. Or maybe you just want _constituent_. Clauses, phrases, and individual words are constituents.

Comment: This Q's an example of what's wrong with using terminology to provide real meaning. A [sentence](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sentence) can be one word long; a phrase can be much longer. So the Q should be something like: "_What's more than merely a word but not quite a complete sentence?_" "..._because she cheated on me all the time_" is a subordinate clause: _because_ is a subordinating conjunction. Remove the _because_ and "she...time" is an independent clause: a complete sentence.

Comment: Elliptical Ss can be called "complete sentences" because they're [utterances that can stand alone](http://englishonline.tki.org.nz/English-Online/Exploring-language/Sentences) {Bloomfield 1926}. Ergo, _Tarzan, what's her name?_ is a sentence, & _Jane._ is a sentence (elliptical because "Her name is" has been elided but is easily inferred in context). I like John Lawler's suggestion: "constituent": There's no need to get technical & specific unless you're teaching a linguistics or grammar class. General terms are often good enough & even preferable in nonspecialist discussions.

Comment: _Sentence fragments_ is an alternative term for elliptical sentences; _string_ describes a string (!) of consecutive words not necessarily able sensibly to stand alone.

Comment: @Edwin: Another terminology problem. If I mistype a word, should I be considered guilty of a spelling error, a typographical error, a proofreading error, or, in the case of a homophone, a cognitive error (a _thinko_)? Some sentence fragments exist because the writer doesn't know, eg, there* no verb, but the verb's required [*as in this example]. Others exist because they're complete sentence responses to questions that don't have to be repeated in the response, except in grammar school & grammar classes, for boring pedagogical reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic grammatical units are *morpheme, word, phrase, clause* and *sentence*. In the definition given in the ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken English’, a phrase is ‘a structural unit built from words, consisting of a head plus (optionally) modifiers.’ In 'The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language', David Crystal puts it a little differently: 'A cluster of words smaller than a clause, forming a grammatical unit.' (He mentions that it is sometimes called a 'group'. This is the term used in functional grammar.) To take an example, the sentence ‘Egyptians have approved a controversial new constitution’ contains two phrases: ‘Egyptians’ and ‘a controversial new constitution’.

This is the generally understood use of *phrase*. It is not to be confused with its use in the approach to grammar known as ‘immediate constituent analysis’. There, *phrase* is used rather differently, in that a sentence is divided into a Noun Phrase and a Verb Phrase, and each of those is further divided into all the constituent parts of the sentence.

Comment: I am always eager to learn, so I'd be grateful if the down-voter would explain anything I've got wrong or have omitted.

Answer (score 9):

The definition of a **phrase** is *a sequence of words that do not form a sentence*.

By "sequence" I mean they are normally in some order, or at least not separated by full stops or line-endings and such. So a list of words is not a phrase.

In some situations, it makes sense to include single words in what count as phrases, but usually a phrase consists of more than one word.

In certain modern branches of linguistics, a phrase is sometimes a sequence of words that form a [constituent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_%28linguistics%29). But usually something like a *noun phrase* is rather a *kind* of phrase, a constituent phrase, as opposed to non-constituent phrases.

---

Your examples, however, could be said to be *sentences*, though not *full* or *complete sentences*: they can be introduced with a capital and ended with a sentence-ending stop, but they are probably not (full) clauses.

> Good job!
>
> Nice shirt!

You could say these are elliptical clauses and hence elliptical complete sentences, because they do not syntactically depend on any (other) clause and the omitted words can be easily supplied:

> [You have done a] good job!
>
> [That's a] nice shirt!

---

A *clause* is conventionally a phrase that contains a finite verb and (all) its constituents. In (certain recent branches of?) Anglo-Saxon linguistics, any verb will do, not just finite verbs.