# The difference between a clause and a phrase?

Tags: phrases, clauses

This question [What is the difference between a phrase and a clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5356/what-is-the-difference-between-a-phrase-and-a-clause) has an answer, with no embedded examples. The link it provides is not longer active, giving a `404 page not found error`. *Please don't close this as a duplicate until it, at least, has some answers.*

The answer to the duplicate explains the differences between clauses and phrases, but fails to answer my question, as this is the explanation given:

> The short answer: clauses contain a subject and its verb, while phrases do not. Note that phrases may contain nouns and verbals, but won't have the noun as the verb's actor.

- I do not understand what is meant by *verbals* and the *noun as the verb's actor* may as well be written in Swedish (of which I know not one word!).

So I am posting this question again, as my question has not been answered. Clauses and phrases were the only thing I failed when studying English at school and forever it has been difficult for me to grasp (I don't think it was explained well, as I had a similar problem with positive and negative numbers the same year, and went on the excel at high level maths).

I am looking to understand the very basics of what a clause is, what a phrase is, and by understanding these definitions it, hopefully, will be clear what the differences are.

Can anyone, please, explain this and provide embedded answers?

Comment: So what you really want to know is what *verbals* are and what *noun as the verb's actor* means. Those are two separate questions, which you can ask without asking about phrases and clauses!

Comment: @MattЭллен I am simply stating that the answer to the duplicate question does not provide an answer to my question, what is a clause and a phrase. I am illustrating why it doesn't and what sort of answer I require. Please read my question again. It really is in plain English tx

Comment: I suggest you begin by looking [here](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/clauses/ex1.htm) (and linked pages), but be aware that terminologies (and even approaches) differ.

Comment: The problem is that different people have different definitions of *clause* and different definitions of *phrase*. The traditional definition of a clause is "a finite verb and its dependencies". A finite verb is one that has to agree with its (implied) subject, so *walks* if the subject is he/she/it, *walk* otherwise. Participles and infinitives are not finite verbs. The traditional definition of a phrase is "any sequence of words", so in theory a clause is a kind of phrase according to that definition, but a phrase need not be a clause.

Comment: Others define *clause* as "any verb and its dependencies" and *phrase* as "any sequence of words that form a constituent".

Comment: Relevant: [Longer than a word — smaller than a sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95256/longer-than-a-word-smaller-than-a-sentence/95258#95258)

Comment: @Cerberus no wonder I had trouble learning it, 35 years ago!!! thanks for your help.. I have a grammar book, but it's interesting, there's a block there since I didn't grasp it as a child.

Comment: @Cerberus do you care to porivde an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was perusing the net on the hunt for reliable sources to help me understand the subjunctive mood when I came across this section and it reminded me of this question!

I'll quote it in almost its entirety because first, it's very clear and it might be of help to other users and secondly, I liked it.

[**Clause and Phrases**](http://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/gram_clauses_n_phrases.html)

> **I.** A phrase is a collection of words that may have nouns or verbals,
>   but it does not have a subject doing a verb. The following are
>   examples of phrases:
>
> - leaving behind the dog
> - smashing into a fence
> - before the first test
> - after the devastation
> - between ignorance and intelligence
> - broken into thousands of pieces
> - because of her glittering smile
>
> In these examples above, you will find nouns (dog, fence, test, devastation, ignorance,
>   intelligence, thousands, pieces). You also have some verbals (leaving,
>   smashing), but in no case is the noun functioning as a subject doing a
>   predicate verb. They are all phrases.
>
> **II.** A clause is a collection of words that has a subject that is
>   actively doing a verb. The following are examples of clauses:
>
> - since she laughs at diffident men
> - I despise individuals of low character
> - when the saints go marching in
> - Obediah Simpson is uglier than a rabid raccoon
> - because she smiled at him.
>
> In the examples above, we find either a noun or a pronoun that is a subject (bold) attached to a predicate verb (italics) in each case:
>
> - since **she** *laughs* at diffident men
> - **I** *despise* individuals of low character
> - when the **saints** *go marching* in
> - **Obediah Simpson** *is* uglier than a rabid raccoon
> - because **she** *smiled* at him
>
> **III.** If the clause could stand by itself, and form a complete sentence with punctuation, we call the clause an independent clause. The following are independent clauses:
>
> - I despise individuals of low character
> - Obediah Simpson is uglier than a rabid racoon
>
> We could easily turn independent clauses into complete sentences by adding appropriate punctuation marks. We might say, "I despise individuals of low character." Or we might write, "Obediah Simpson is uglier than a rabid racoon!" We call them independent because these types of clauses can stand independently by themselves, without any extra words attached, and be complete sentences.

Comment: It's hard to think of someone *doing something* by being uglier than a rabid raccoon, :) but I guess they are

Comment: I don't have a pet, unless you count my boyfriend. He often purrs and miaows around the house. :)

Comment: Boyfriends count :)

Comment: A downvote, and yet the answer is copied verbatim. The writer's credentials are impressive, as too his [resumè or CV](http://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/cv.html) if you prefer. But that doesn't matter; what matters is that I always get at least one downvote per day. It's become a standard procedure. And always by cowards too, funny that.

Comment: I get that on [pets.se] and often on [cogsci.se]. I think people get jealous

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11442/discussion-between-skippy-and-mari-lou-a)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that different people have different definitions of clause and different definitions of phrase.

The traditional definition of a **clause** is "a finite verb and its dependencies". A finite verb is one that has to agree with its (implied) subject, so walks if the subject is he/she/it, walk otherwise. Participles and infinitives are not finite verbs. By dependencies are meant all complements and satellites to a verb, so subject, object, adjuncts, etc.

The traditional definition of a **phrase** is "any sequence of words", so in theory a clause is a kind of phrase according to that definition, but a phrase need not be a clause.

Others define *clause* as "any verb and its dependencies" and *phrase* as "any sequence of words that forms a constituent".

Comment: As usual, even the most basic terms have not been unarguably defined.

Answer (score 0):

As stated earlier the presence of two or more words in an expression is enough to raise our suspicion that it is a  phrase or a clause.For it to be accepted as a clause, two features have to be identified:  1.A finite verb  2. A subject